# Save button of pinterest doesn't work for anonymous user

Tags: javascript, pinterest

Like we share the url in facebook and twitter, I need to do similar kind of thing with Pinterest where user can save/pin any image url of my site into their Pinterest board.

I have gone through the [documentation](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/widgets/save/?) of Pinterest which works fine for me if the user is already logged-in in Pinterest but *For the anonymous user it opens the Pinterest login window and stays in the pinterest home page after successful login. The image url to be saved is lost somewhere.*

Am I missing something in documentation or Is it the way it works?
Need a little help here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question to the Pinterest support and they clarified that this is the way 'Save button' works and they will look into it to see if they can change the way it works